# ServiceNow Service Portal modal windows

Tags: modal-dialog, widget, servicenow

Very new to Service Portal and modal windows.  I'm creating a portal page and want to include modal windows for a couple different things.  First, I want a modal welcome note to appear when a user lands on it for the first time.  I've already created the welcome note in an HTML widget, but am confused how that would interact with the modal widget that comes with Service Portal.  Secondly, I've created some links (also using HTML widget) that would take a user to a knowledge article and would like to utilize modal windows as well.  After playing around with the modal widget, I'm confused what to enter in each of these boxes in order for it to work correctly:

[image]

Also is this meant to work with other widgets in Service Portal or is it easier to create a new widget and just code the modal part of it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different options for modals in service now. My two favorites being `$uibModal` which is a standard bootstrap modal implementation in angular and there is `spModal`.

angular-ui.github.com

https://github.com/service-portal/documentation/blob/master/documentation/spModal.md

As far as coding the modals, you can do that if you choose too, it is a tad more difficult as you will need to know and understand angular as well as the ng-template implementation inside of service portal.

Play around with these and see if they fit your needs and go from there.

On your second question, those are referenced in your widgets table under the service portal application. I would suggest using the `sp-widget` directive that servicenow provides, as opposed to the instance creation method. In my opinion, the instance method is more rigid and less flexible. I do very advanced UI/UX implementations and directives (hopefully the implement components soon) are really the most flexible option.

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/build/service-portal/concept/c_NestedWidgets.html